# How to show error response on alertDialog box in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the below code to validate and show response on alertDialog boxes.I am trying to print if the response is error I would like to print it on the alert dialog box.but it was not printing anything on the alert box.Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

```
private void logIn(final String userName, final String passWord) {
        new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String ... params) {
                try {
                    HttpBackgroundTask http = new HttpBackgroundTask(Endpoints.URL_LOGIN);
                    JSONObject resp = http.login(userName, passWord);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + resp.toString());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Message"+resp.get("message"));
                    if(resp.get("code") == "403"){
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid email and password");
                        alertDialog.setTitle("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+"Alert Message");
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        alertDialog.create().show();
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if(resp.get("code") == "200"){
                        testFeed();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return "";
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```

Comment: what is showing currently on your alert dialog?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `resp.get("code").equals("403")` instead of `resp.get("code") == ("403")`.

**2.** Use `alertDialog.setTitle(resp.get("message"))` to show error `message` on `dialog`.

**Try this:**

```
private void logIn(final String userName, final String passWord) {
    new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String ... params) {
            try {
                HttpBackgroundTask http = new HttpBackgroundTask(Endpoints.URL_LOGIN);
                JSONObject resp = http.login(userName, passWord);
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + resp.toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Message"+resp.get("message"));

                if(resp.get("code").equals("403")){
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid email and password");
                    alertDialog.setTitle(resp.get("message"));
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);                        
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.create().show();
                }
                if(resp.get("code") == "200"){
                    testFeed();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return "";
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

**FYI,** make sure the `response` contains key `code` with value `403` otherwise the `dialog` will not show.

**UPDATE:**

> com.example.arunmannuru.arun E/HttpBackgroundTask: Can't create
>   handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

**Try this:**

```
private void logIn(final String userName, final String passWord) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>() {

                ...........
                ....................
            }.execute();
        }
     });
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: check your log >>> Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + resp.toString());
                Log.d(TAG,"Message"+resp.get("message"));

Comment: com.example.arunmannuru.arun E/HttpBackgroundTask: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()  ...Showing this error on log.

Comment: I have updated my nswer.execute asynctask from UI thread using runOnUiThread().

Comment: from where your logIn method called?

Comment: onClick listener method